# Fidning max/min value of a list in pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-import

I know this is a very trivial question, and I am quite surprised I could not find an answer on the internet, but can one find the max or min value o a list in pyspark?
In Python it is easily done by

```
max(list)
```

However, when I try the same in pyspark I get the following error:

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method max([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:276)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE: Adding what exactly I did:**
This is my list:

`cur_datelist`

Output:

```
['2020-06-10', '2020-06-11', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-21', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-23', '2020-06-24', '2020-06-25', '2020-06-26', '2020-06-27', '2020-06-28', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-03', '2020-07-04', '2020-07-05', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09', '2020-07-10', '2020-07-11', '2020-07-12', '2020-07-13', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-15', '2020-07-16', '2020-07-17', '2020-07-18', '2020-07-19', '2020-07-20', '2020-07-21', '2020-07-22', '2020-07-23', '2020-07-24', '2020-07-25', '2020-07-26', '2020-07-27', '2020-07-28', '2020-07-29', '2020-07-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-01', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-07', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-09', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-11', '2020-08-12', '2020-08-13', '2020-08-14', '2020-08-15', '2020-08-16', '2020-08-17', '2020-08-18', '2020-08-19', '2020-08-20', '2020-08-21', '2020-08-22', '2020-08-23', '2020-08-24', '2020-08-25', '2020-08-26', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-29', '2020-08-30', '2020-08-31']
```

The class is 'list':
`type(cur_datelist)`

> <class 'list'>

I assumed that to be a normal pythonic list.
So when I tried `max(cur_datelist)`, I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: You don't just call something like `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max([1,2,3,4])`. `max` is a data frame function that takes a column as argument. If you have a Python list, call the built-in function just as you did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not different between pyspark and python for the list but the column is difference. This is the result of my pyspark.

```
# just a list
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(max(l))

# 3

# dataframe with the array column
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [1, 2, 3]), (2, [4, 5, 6])]).toDF('id', 'list')

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('max', f.array_max(f.col('list'))).show()

#+---+---------+---+
#| id|     list|max|
#+---+---------+---+
#|  1|[1, 2, 3]|  3|
#|  2|[4, 5, 6]|  6|
#+---+---------+---+
```

Your error comes from the `max` function overlap between the python native one and the spark column function! To avoid this, specify your pyspark function. Then `max` denotes the python original.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

l = ['2020-06-10', '2020-06-11', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-21', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-23', '2020-06-24', '2020-06-25', '2020-06-26', '2020-06-27', '2020-06-28', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-03', '2020-07-04', '2020-07-05', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09', '2020-07-10', '2020-07-11', '2020-07-12', '2020-07-13', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-15', '2020-07-16', '2020-07-17', '2020-07-18', '2020-07-19', '2020-07-20', '2020-07-21', '2020-07-22', '2020-07-23', '2020-07-24', '2020-07-25', '2020-07-26', '2020-07-27', '2020-07-28', '2020-07-29', '2020-07-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-01', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-07', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-09', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-11', '2020-08-12', '2020-08-13', '2020-08-14', '2020-08-15', '2020-08-16', '2020-08-17', '2020-08-18', '2020-08-19', '2020-08-20', '2020-08-21', '2020-08-22', '2020-08-23', '2020-08-24', '2020-08-25', '2020-08-26', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-29', '2020-08-30', '2020-08-31']
print(max(l))

# 2020-08-31
```

Or,

```
import builtins as p

print(p.max(l))
# 2020-08-31
```

Comment: But my list is not in a dataframe,  it is just a simple list of class `list`
Using f.array_max(list) did not work. Do I absolutely have to force it into a dataframe in order to use the array_max function?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Your list is not the dataframe, then it is a normal list right? In my answer, `max(l)` would work.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the exact list and what I tried. 
Is that not a true pythonic list?

Comment: Finally, figure out what is wrong. Your max function overlap.

Comment: I thought I was being efficient by doing ```from pyspark.sql.functions import *```. I guess I have to call ```f.everything``` :P
It's the little things. Thank you so much for pointing that out for me! :)

Comment: You can use in the other way, `import builtins as py_builtin` and `py_buildin.max` for the native one.