# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [79, -1, -1] of type <class 'list'> column literals use 'lit' 'array' 'struct' or 'create_map'

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a problem in PySpark UDF, it is throwing below error

```
PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [79, -1, -1] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

I'm trying to get a number according to the precedence array, and their precedence is reduced as they from left to right.

```
precedence = [1,2,11,12,13,20,20131,200,202,203,210,220,223,226,235,236,237,242,244,245,247,253,254,257,259,260,262,278,283,701,20107,20108,20109,20112,20115,20123,20135,20141,20144,20152,20162,20163,20167,20168,20169,20170,20171,20172,20173,20174,20175,14,211,213,258,270,273,274,275,277,280,281,287,288,20120,20122,20124,20125,20126,20130,20133,20136,20137,20138,20140,20142,20143,20154,20155,20156,20157]
reverse_order = precedence[::-1]

def get_p(row):
    if (row!=None) and (row!="null"):
        temp = row.split(",")
        test = []
        for i in temp:
            if (i.find('=')!=-1):
                i = i.split('=')[0]
            if int(i) in reverse_order:
                test.append(reverse_order.index(int(i)))
            else:
                test.append(-1)
        if max(test)!=-1:
            return reverse_order[max(test)]
        return -999
    else:
        return None

get_array = udf(get_p, IntegerType())

bronze_table = bronze_table.withColumn("precedence", get_array("event_list"))
bronze_table.select("event_list","precedence").show(100, False)
```

Here are the sample records,

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|event_list                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|276,100,101,202,176                                                                    |
|276,100,2,124,176                                                                      |
|246,100,101,257,115,116,121,123,124,125,135,138,145,146,153,167,168,170,171,173,189,191|
|246,100,101,278,123,124,135,170,189,191                                                |
|20131=16,20151,100,101,102,115,116,121,123,124,125,135,138,145,146,153,168,170,171     |
|null                                                                                   |
|20107=9,20151,100,101,102,123,124,135,170,189,191                                      |
|20108=3,20151,100,101,102,123,124,125,135,170,171,189,191                              |
|null                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I am expecting

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|event_list                                                                             |precedence|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|276,100,101,202,176                                                                    |202       |
|276,100,2,124,176                                                                      |2         |
|246,100,101,257,115,116,121,123,124,125,135,138,145,146,153,167,168,170,171,173,189,191|257       |
|246,100,101,278,123,124,135,170,189,191                                                |278       |
|20131=16,20151,100,101,102,115,116,121,123,124,125,135,138,145,146,153,168,170,171     |20131     |
|null                                                                                   |null      |
|20107=9,20151,100,101,102,123,124,135,170,189,191                                      |20107     |
|20108=3,20151,100,101,102,123,124,125,135,170,171,189,191                              |20108     |
|null                                                                                   |null      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

my `UDF` is working as expected in python, but not working in pyspark. I request someone to please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone, who tried to solve the problem. I'm able to solve it using this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/63654269/6187792

The issue with max function, as specified in the link.

Here is the updated code.

```
import builtins as p
def get_p(row):
    if (row!=None) and (row!="null"):
        temp = row.split(",")
        test = []
        for i in temp:
            if (i.find('=')!=-1):
                i = i.split('=')[0]
            if int(i) in reverse_order:
                test.append(reverse_order.index(int(i)))
            else:
                test.append(-1)
        if p.max(test)!=-1:
            return reverse_order[p.max(test)]
        return None
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with `max` function. The issue is the way you importing PySpark functions is incorrect. So, instead of `import builtins as p` then use builtin functions like `p.max`, you should do `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` then use `F.udf` or `F.col`.

Answer (score 0):

`null` in PySpark dataframe is `None` in Python, so this condition `if row!="null":` is incorrect. Try `if row!= None:` instead.

However, your `get_p` function doesn't run well to me, for example:

```py
get_p('276,100,101,202,176')
# output: 2
# expected: 202

get_p('20131=16,20151,100,101,102,115,116,121,123,124,125,135,138,145,146,153,168,170,171')
# output: Exception `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`
# expected: 20131
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, i did update get_p function, @pltc